# Iterate through Retrofit response

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit for my Android app, calling it like this:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
        .build();

ApiEndpointInterface apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);

apiService.getFeed(9, new Callback<Post>() {

    @Override
    public void success(Post post, Response response) {
        // loop
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        retrofitError.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

The JSON is formatted like this:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "data":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "user_id":"2",
            "message":"Hello, world!"
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "user_id":"1",
            "message":"Another hello!"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I iterate through each item and, for example, print its message to console? Each item belongs to the `Post` model:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Post {
    public String id;
    public String userId;
    public String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your model class? As per your model class I shall help you.

Comment: Edited the original post to include the model.

Answer (score 1):

Your Main model class look like this.

```
public class Post {
        private String success;
        private List<data> data;

        public List<data> getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Here is your data class.You need to create another class to retrieve json arary(For you it is data.)

```
public class data {
    public String id;
    public String userId;
    public String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}

apiService.getFeed(9, new Callback<Post>() {

    @Override
    public void success(Post post, Response response) {
        post.getData().getPositoin(YourPosition).getMessage(); //or you can use for loop

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        retrofitError.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```